# Javascript / Vue3 - Mixins - Return 'null' by default

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-mixin

I'm building a basic 'required' form validation function.  Here's the function:

JS:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        required(string) {
            if (!string) {
                return 'This field is required!'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input id="username"
  v-model="credentials.username"
  type="text"
  name="username"
/>
<span>{{ required(credentials.username) }}</span>
```

The above works great.  If I start typing in the input, the returned value goes null.  If I empty the input, the returned value comes back as expected, "This field is required".

My question is, how can I return the value as null/blank to start?  Expected flow is:

- Returned value is null/blank to start
- User starts typing, nothing changes because string.length != 0
- User deletes all characters, causing string.length == 0, causing the returned value to be 'This field is required!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use an `input`-event handler (called for every new value in the input) that sets a flag to indicate the field is "dirty". Then conditionally render the validation result (the `<span>`) based on the flag:

1. Declare a data property named `"dirty"`:

   ```js
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         dirty: false,
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. In the template, add an `input`-event handler on the `<input>` that sets the `dirty` flag:

   ```html
   <input @input="dirty = true">
   ```
3. Also, conditionally render the `<span>` field based on `dirty`:

   ```html
   <span v-if="dirty">{{ required(credentials.username) }}</span>
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rNyqvyz)